# Dependence injection to initialize driver in cucumber project and use hook without terminating session

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, appium

I`m trying to implement cucumber with Page Object Model and i faced couple problems and have lots of questions.

1. My iOS app is not that complex, but i still want to orginize all stepdefs and features to correspond with pages from POM. So i will have multiple stepdefs and runners. What is best practice to organize all of it ? I tried Pico DI, but wasn`t even able to pass my driver instance through it.( If you can, please provide structure solution)
2. Since it`s native iOS - I`m not going to close app after every scenario( it will take forever). But I still want to keep features DRY for re-usability 
   What would be the best way to create one appium driver instance and never create another until feature is executed? I understand i just need to add driver.quit in the last step. What i`m straggling with is to use same driver throughout all project(Pages, Stepdefs) (see code)
3. Im going to run tests with TestNg and wonder if @Before @After annotations still work in stepdefs or it`s better to avoid them ?
4. The MAIN question : Dependency Injection with pico. Since all my tests are acceptance (end to end feature tests) i wonder if it is good idea to create one InjectionSetUp class which will contain all my pages AND driver

*Driver manager*

```java
public class IOSDriverManager {
    public static ThreadLocal<IOSDriver<IOSElement>> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<IOSDriver<IOSElement>>();

 public static DesiredCapabilities getIOSCapsLocal() {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
         //My caps
  return caps;

 public static void createThreadLocalWebDriver() {
        IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = null;
//try catch
      driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL(APPIUM_SERVER_URL), getIOSCapsLocal());
//try catch
        webDriver.set(driver);
 }
 public static IOSDriver<IOSElement> getThreadLocalDriver() {
        IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = webDriver.get();
        if (driver == null) {
            createThreadLocalWebDriver();
            driver = webDriver.get();
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

*BasePage*

```java
public class BasePage {
    IOSDriver<IOSElement> Driver;
    public BasePage(IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver) {
     initElements();
     Driver = driver;
    }

    private void initElements() {

        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(getDriver()),this);
    }

    protected IOSDriver<IOSElement> getDriver() {
        return IOSDriverManager.getThreadLocalDriver();
    }

}
```

*AnyPage*

```java
public class BiosurveyPage extends BasePage {
 public BiosurveyPage(IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver) {
        super(driver); //  Appiumfield  decorator is applied by BasePage constructor
//Is it better to just use getDriver() method throughout all pages instead of declaring driver again ? 
    }
```

*Finaly StepDefs*

```java
public class newSignUpFlowTest{
    protected IOSDriver<IOSElement> getDriver() {
        return IOSDriverManager.getThreadLocalDriver();
    }
    LoginPage poLogin = new LoginPage(getDriver());
    SignUpPage poSignup = new SignUpPage(getDriver());
      // 10+ pages 

@Given("I am on Login Page")
    public void iAmOnLoginPage() {
        assertThat("ON LOGIN PAGE",poLogin.isLoginScreen(),equalTo(true));
    }

    @When("I tap on Sign Up Link")
    public void iTapsOnSignUpLink() {
        poLogin.clickSignUp();
    }
// 20+ methods for this feature
```

**UPDATE**
I fixed everything and able to run tests. Now my question is - does my framework look decent ? I don`t have any real life experience prior to this. So can someone just approve me and suggest enhancements to keep up with best industry practices ?  I know this post might piss some people off, but i don`t know where else to communicate this as i don`t have any friends in the QA field and working remotely

Comment: With your update it sounds like you are asking for a code review. For that I recommend https://code review.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using dependency injection you want to let your DI system do all the heavy lifting. So your step definitions have a constructor dependency on your page objects.

```
public class NewSignUpFlowStepDefinitions {

    private final LoginPage poLogin;
    private final SignUpPage poSignup;

    NewSignUpFlowStepDefinitions(LoginPage poLogin, SignUpPage poSignup) {
        this.poLogin = poLogin;
        this.poSignup = poSignup;
    }

    @Given("I am on Login Page")
    public void iAmOnLoginPage() {
        assertThat("ON LOGIN PAGE", poLogin.isLoginScreen(), equalTo(true));
    }

    @When("I tap on Sign Up Link")
    public void iTapsOnSignUpLink() {
        poLogin.clickSignUp();
    }

}
```

You page objects can't have a constructor dependency on `IOSDriver<IOSElement>` because PicoContainer can only create dependency chains that don't end with empty constructors. So instead we use the `IOSDriverManager` here.

```
public class BiosurveyPage extends BasePage {
    public BiosurveyPage(IOSDriverManager driverManager) {
        super(driverManager);
    }
}
```

In your `BasePage` you then unpack the webdriver from the driver manager.

```
public abstract class BasePage {
    private IOSDriverManager driverManager;

    public BasePage(IOSDriverManager driverManager) {
        this.driverManager = driverManager;
        initElements();
    }

    private void initElements() {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driverManager.getDriver()), this);
    }

    protected IOSDriver<IOSElement> getDriver() {
        return driverManager.getDriver();

    }
}
```

Then in the `IOSDriverManager` you can keep a reference to the webdriver and create it as needed. If you are certain it is safe to share your webdriver between scenarios you can still use a `ThreadLocal` here.

```
public class IOSDriverManager implements Disposable{
    private IOSDriver<IOSElement> webDriver;

    private DesiredCapabilities getIOSCapsLocal() {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        return caps;
    }

    private void createWebDriver() {
        webDriver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL(APPIUM_SERVER_URL), getIOSCapsLocal());
    }

    public IOSDriver<IOSElement> getDriver() {
        if (webDriver == null) {
            createThreadLocalWebDriver();
        }
        return webDriver;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // Stop webdriver ehre
    }
}
```

Note that `Disposable` adds the dispose method which will let you clean up your driver a after each scenario. Either to dispose it entirely or to reset it to some known state.

http://picocontainer.com/lifecycle.html

Comment: Thank you a lot for such a great answer
Last thing I`m struggling with is how to add my WaitUtils and AssertUtils to BasePage constructor.
If i just keep it like that 'public BasePage(IOSDriverManager driverManager) {
        this.driverManager = driverManager;
        initElements();
        asrt= new AssertUtils;
    }'  I get some PICOCONTAINER exception 
I tried to create second constructor - but getting nullPointer for all methods that use waitUtils

Comment: Might be easier to create a new question to share all the details. It's really hard say what goes wrong here.

Comment: Got it fixed somehow, not even sure how.